# Cell phone as data feed to wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

my cable internet went down yesterday and I've been trying to get that corrected.  Since my cell phone can also be used as a tethered modem, is there a way to feed my router with the data feed from my phone?  I'm really thinking about this more as a kind of emergency option.  Even though the cell phone can also be used as a wireless router, I have computers on the system which are hardwired into my current wireless router, so that isn't a complete solution.

So, I guess there are two questions:

1. are there any wireless routers that support USB->micro USB for a cell phone connection?
2. are there any cable options that could provide power to the phone and an Ethernet jack back to my wireless router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect the cellphone to one of the computers connected to the network, and have that computer act as the internet gateway

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you for your help.   I don't often have to think about the network side of things and appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's an emergency situation only, I would tether the phone to my desktop PC, and then bridge the Wireless and Ethernet adapters together, so that the desktop would become the new gateway.

I have also sold Netgear routers that have a USB port which allows a standard 3G USB stick for a backup connection. This may be a possible solution too, though I'm not sure how the tethering side would work.

Comment: Wouldn't he also need to enable internet connection sharing and connect his computer to the router via the uplink port?

Comment: Yes, that would probably resolve the "use the router as well" problem. My solution didn't take that into account.