# Use USB Tethering for local router as internet Gateway

Tags: networking, router, internet, android, gateway

I want to use a local router as a node for all devices to connect to internet instead of Android Hot-Spot.

Reason: Because connecting to Android requires manipulating the NAT on multiple phones just to connect two devices with each other and there are multiple devices.

Attempted Solution 1:

1. Connected a phone to WiFi that has internet (to act as internet gateway for the router instead of of the regular cable)
2. Connected the same phone to the router using USB-Tethering from phone, the USB Port is working fine (the LED is giving green color indicate that) but the internet LED gives red color (Indication that it is trying to detect internet gateway) but it never turns green.

What am I missing or should look up at the internet because I failed drastically?

Similar Problems to mine:

1. [Using cell phone as Internet provider for router](https://superuser.com/q/1204096/1171783)
2. [Cell phone as data feed to wireless router](https://superuser.com/questions/416811/cell-phone-as-data-feed-to-wireless-router)
3. [Use Smartphone as gateway to internet for my local network (Not smartphone hotspot!)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035072/use-smartphone-as-gateway-to-internet-for-my-local-network-not-smartphone-hotsp?newreg=9455675e025443a4be5d5323b68b4957)

Some Information that might be helpful or relevant:

1. I have multiple PCs that can only be connected via LAN (They are far from each other to the extent that not even a Wi-Fi Module can connect them to the router)
2. Router Type: ZXHN H168 V3.1
3. Thought of making a device act as the gateway but then, I am not sure if the devices are going to communicate with each other nicely (without needing to manually edit the NAT) & do not know how to do so and not to mention that the only device capable of doing this is a laptop because it has both Wi-Fi and LAN.
4. [Image of the entire connection described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alb9b.png)

(update) Attempted Solution 2: (Inspired from this [site](https://www.tecmint.com/share-internet-in-linux/))

Tried to use my Linux Laptop to be the WAN gateway.

1. The router detects the connection.
2. Pinging the Laptop from other devices gives me `From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 packet filtered`.
3. The laptop does not see any device on the local network (I used `sudo arp-scan --interface=enp7s0 --localnet` & Tried to access the router page using my browser but the laptop does not see the router (Error 404 when loading 192.168.1.1)).

Comment: Does your router actually claim to support USB network connections? If the port is meant for printers and storage devices, that doesn't guarantee it'll work with network interfaces.

Comment: To be honest, not sure; but there is a WAN 3G option in the router settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unfortunately a lot of different protocols that could be used to provide networking over USB – some devices use a generic protocol like CDC ECM or CDC EEM or CDC NCM, Android phones in "USB tethering" mode provide RNDIS, and of course there are many USB-Ethernet products requiring custom drivers.

But 3G modems might use *none of the above* as their primary interface; if your router claims "3G WAN" support, it's likely that it expects the USB device to provide a *serial port* for AT communications, much like dial-up modems (and pre-smartphone GPRS/HSPA tethering) in the past. The router would ask the modem to "dial" `*99#` for Internet access.

(And for 4G modems, it would be a serial port for MBIM/QMI; they do provide an ECM network interface alongside, but it only becomes active once specific "connect" commands are sent via MBIM first.)

Of course, the router *could* support several kinds of USB network interfaces, but it's very likely that the manufacturer had focus on AT-based 3G modems specifically, and didn't even think about including support for RNDIS that's required for Android USB tethering.

Comment: Then, is there any kind off adapter that overcome such limitations and connect each other? I though of using RPI as a device to share internet (much like a phone except it will connect using Ethernet instead of USB) but then i though that this is an over kill and there must be a simpler solution.